# What do I need to do to make a former chicken run a child-safe part of my garden?

Tags: safety, chickens

We have 6 chickens in an outdoor covered run in our garden, and have had for around 3 years. We are planning to relocate them and would like to reclaim this area as part of our garden, safe for young children to play.

I'm concerned about residual poo, disease and parasites which could potentially be left in the ground, which is typically rather unpleasant right now. We do maintain a layer of wood chippings which are periodically replaced but what else would we need to do before allowing children to play in this area? Is there a time component as well as any practical tasks we should do?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I am not absolutely sure, if this is at scope here... Did you consider to try parenting.SE or even biology.SE?

Comment: @Allerleirauh not fully within the scope of Parenting SE, the medical advice part is clearly off topic there, so as long as that’s the main focus, it would be closed. Not sure about Biology SE. You could rephrase this as “how long do parasites persist in the soil”, that should be on topic here, iirc we had something similar a few years ago?

Comment: I originally thought to ask in Gardening but there are no relevant questions. It certainly isn't relevant for parenting... surely "how to clean up after your pets "is on-topic here, if anywhere? It might have no ideal SE site but this seems as good a place

Comment: I don't know enough to write a full answer. But I know lots of people who grew up playing in chicken coops with chickens as young kids, me included. We're all fine ;) 

I would think you could just lightly treat the area. Maybe remove the top layers of mulch or soil, or just churn it up and let it rest. Cold weather could kill top level bacteria or parasites. I know high temps kills salmonella, which is the common concern between kids and chickens, so you could maybe burn the area (contained, of course, and depending on laws).

Comment: this question might be a better fit over at https://gardening.stackexchange.com/ if the area is exposed to sunlight and weather it will get safer over time but soil can never be totally safe,the same is true for any other surface like the floor in our houses where the children and our pets move around.

Comment: What is there between the hard soil and the wood chippings? I would expect some good layer of sand... The answer is going to be strongly influenced by this info.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some brainstorming:

1. Use generous amounts of hydrogen peroxide. After it finishes its disinfection job, it transforms into water. Ideally, you should find higher concentration H2O2 - the pharmacy stuff is only 3%, so mostly just water.
2. Collect whatever you can from above the hard soil (sand, wood chippings...). Heat them to above 50 C. Be sure to not melt them. Also, it might generate important amounts of disgusting odors - preferable to be done outside. In case of big quantity, run several batches.
3. Use UV-C lamps over the area. Be warned that the UV-C radiation can have adverse, undesirable effects on living organisms. Proceed with care. Use your favorite search engine on how to use UV-C safely.

---

How you can verify that the area is "safe"? By yourself, you can not. Only some specialized service might be able to run that kind of evaluation.

---

For the most of the history, people (children included) lived together with their animals and birds. An occasionally, even ate them. Sometimes, they ate them even raw. So it is not out of the question that the area would be safe-enough even without any special treatment. Just replace the top layer of whatever you have there (sand, wood chippings).